# Making password characters hidden in Vuetify field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

So here is my password field in vuetify :

```
<v-text-field
  label="Password"
  v-model="password"
  required
></v-text-field>
```

But when i enter text it's in clear and not *****

How to make a vuetify password textfield so when a user type it will show only ***** and not what the user is typing.

regards and thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add the `type="password"` to your input component.

```
<v-text-field type="password"> </v-text-field>
```

You can check the [`Vuetify Documentation`](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/text-fields#example-10) for password field properties.

Comment: No need to add it as a static string variable, simply use ```type="password"```

Answer (score 9):

```
<v-text-field type="password"></v-text-field>
```

I tried the accepted answer, but it did not work for me. Do not bind the type property. Use as a regular input password field.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem as OP and got it to work by using the following (using Vuetify v2.1.0)

```
<v-text-field v-model="form.password" label="Password" type="password"></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is with implemented version:

```js
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
    :append-inner-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye-off' : 'mdi-eye'"
    @click:append-inner="showPassword = !showPassword"
  />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const showPassword = ref(false);
</script>
```